# Why I can't see those properties that are inherited from the parent object when I 'console.log' the object; in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Hi guys I'm learning inheritance in JavaScript recently. I create a `Child` function and make it inherit the `Human` function. I create a `child` instance for `Child` then `console.log(child)`.

I'm wondering why the outputs only have properties of `Child`, but no `Human` property.

I guess it's because the property descriptors, specifically the `enumerable`, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me?

```js
const Child = function() {
  this.name = "child"
}

const Human = function() {
  this.move = "walking";
}

Child.prototype = new Human();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

const child = new Child();
console.log(child);
```

After running above code I only see {name: "child"}, though `console.log(child.move)` gives 'walking'.

Comment: FYI: I see all the properties in Firefox.

Comment: `move` and `constructor` are inherited properties. Maybe your console just doesn't show those? In what environment are you running this code?

Comment: Every object in JS has a `__proto__` link that points to its prototype. If you console `child` in a browser (chrome, firefox), you will get `instance` properties listed followed by `__proto__` link. Once you expand that link, you will see those properties. Here is the image. Hope this helps!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0po8s.png

Comment: thanks guys I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, is that `move` is not found on the `Child` instance, but on the prototype it inherits from `Human`.

Let's analyze your code.

```
const Child = function() {
  this.name = "child"
}

const Human = function() {
  this.move = "walking";
}
```

These are self explanatory, you make two constructor functions. They are unrelated (yet).

```
Child.prototype = new Human();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

This is the inheritance part. `Child.prototype = new Human();` will create an instance of of `Human`, and assign it to `Child.prototype`, because the instance has a member `move`, that gets assigned to `Child.prototype` and you get what's essentially `Child.prototype = { move: 'walking' }` or `Child.prototype.move = 'walking'` (those aren't accurate, but close enough)

Then you assign `Child` itself as the `prototype.constructor`.

---

The reason you're seeing the weird behavior is that you expect `move` to be an instance member, but it's a prototype member instead. A more significant drawback of this effect is that altering `child.move` will alter it for *all child instances at once*, which is not what you'd expect from an instance member.

For this reason, it is not recommended to do inheritance by actually creating an instance, like you did, but using `Object.create()` instead, like so:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

Additionally, your `Child` function should be calling the parent constructor, to maintain the parent's logic and members. Like so:

```
const Child = function() {
  Human.call(this); // call to parent constructor
  this.name = "child";
}
```

Full code:

```js
const Human = function() {
  this.move = "walking";
}
const Child = function() {
  Human.call(this);
  this.name = "child"
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

const child = new Child();
console.log(child);
```

---

Once you understand how prototype chains work, remember that ES6 classes were created to handle these situations more gracefully and with more readable code:

```
class Human {
  constructor() {
    this.move = "walking";
  }
}

class Child extends Human {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "child";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You just lead me to a further level of understanding javascript!